# Ionic4 - ion-select does not correctly update after dynamically added option

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic4

The issue is that `ion-select` multi selection drop-down does not update (selection and as a consequence its control name) after dynamically updating underlying values list.

I have tried triggering change detection manually to pickup the changes but doesn't have an effect.

The following is the minimalistic snippet that illustrates the issue:

```js
@Component({
    selector: 'app-root',
    template: `
        <ion-button color="primary" (click)="AddItem()">Add Item</ion-button>
        <ion-item>
            <ion-label>Broken dropdown</ion-label>
            <ion-select 
                multiple="true"
                placeholder="Broken dropdown"
                [compareWith]="compareWith"
            >
                <ion-select-option *ngFor="let item of stuff" [value]="item" [selected]="item.selected">
                    {{item.name}}
                </ion-select-option>
            </ion-select>
        </ion-item>
    `
})

export class AppComponent {

    public stuff = [{ name: 'item1', selected: false }, { name: 'item2', selected: true }];

    constructor(private platform: Platform, private splashScreen: SplashScreen, private statusBar: StatusBar) { 
        this.initializeApp(); 
    }

    initializeApp() {
        this.platform.ready().then(() => {
            this.statusBar.styleDefault();
            this.splashScreen.hide();
        });
    }

    AddItem() {
        this.stuff.push({ name: 'item3', selected: true });
    }

    compareWith(e1, e2) {
        return e1 && e2 ? e1.name === e2.name : e1 === e2;
    }
}
```

After clicking "Add Item" button I would expect the control name to be updated as well as after opening the drop-down the item2 and item3 would be selected.

I did workaround the issue by manually manipulating control but I would like to understand where the issue is that it doesn't update itself out of the box.

Thanks!

Comment: Same problem. Did you find an answer?

Comment: Solution here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57727662/ion-select-options-wont-refresh-after-changing-the-array-of-objects

Comment: I didn't find an answer but did workaround the issue, you could either manipulate the control directly or use the approach in the link you provided above, both are hacky and not ideal :)